# Running TestNG's RetryAnalizer on a List of tests

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng

I am using TestNG as the Test framework.
I would like to achieve the following:
Once the Test Suite completed, let's say 100 tests were run (where 80 passed, 15 were skipped and 5 failed). In the onExecutionFinish method i start to run the (5) failed tests.

I can get list of failed tests, but how can I make them run once again?

RetryAnalyzer can retry a test after it fails, but I need to retry a bulk of tests after the whole suite has finished.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781098/is-there-anyway-to-rerun-a-test-class-when-it-fails