# How to execute failed test cases using Maven TestNG

Tags: maven, testng

We are using Maven for script execution. For reporting we have used TestNG.
In case test failed for first time we want to re execute those failed tests again.
Is there any option available?

Comment: Maven Surefire provide [this](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#rerunFailingTestsCount) option to re-run failed tests, but only for JUnit apparently

Comment: After failing test you will get a failed test suite in your report directory, Call again this suite file in your maven again

Comment: This will be of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781098/is-there-anyway-to-rerun-a-test-class-when-it-fails

Comment: In case of TestNG when suite execution fails we are deleting all files inside reporting folder. We need to move it to some other folder and again need to pass it as a input to the maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `IRetryAnalyzer` interface to rerun failed test cases with a count to re execute. Add `@Test(retryAnalyzer=<classname>)` to test case.