# Selenium to repeat a specific test step

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests

I have a test method like this:

```
@Test
public void generateReports(String clientname, String username) {
    loginPage().login(clientname, username);
    loginPage().chooseReportManagement();
    reportPage().createReport();
}
```

My goal is to generate 100 reports. My solution right now is to loop the step `createReport()` 100 times, like this:

```
@Test
public void generateReports(String clientname, String username) {
    loginPage().login(clientname, username);
    loginPage().chooseReportManagement();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
        reportPage().createReport();
    }
}
```

It does the task. But I would like to know if there is any other way to achieve this. Because in this way, when something wrong happens when creating a report, the test will be terminated. I want something like, the test should carry on if creating a report is failed, until the loop ends.

I use Selenium and TestNG.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use try/catch:

```
@Test
public void generateReports(String clientname, String username) {
    loginPage().login(clientname, username);
    loginPage().chooseReportManagement();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {
        try {
            reportPage().createReport();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Report creation failed!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should definitely work. Exception won't get down-stack so the test won't fail.

Answer (score 0):

**RetryAnalyzer.class**

```
public class RetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {
 
  int counter = 0;

@Override
public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
 
 // check if the test method had RetryCountIfFailed annotation
 RetryCountIfFailed annotation = result.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod()
 .getAnnotation(RetryCountIfFailed.class);
 // based on the value of annotation see if test needs to be rerun
 if((annotation != null) && (counter < annotation.value()))
 {
 counter++;
 return true;
 }
 return false;
 }
    }
```

**RetryCountIfFailed.class**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RetryCountIfFailed  {
 
 // Specify how many times you want to 
 // retry the test if failed.
 // Default value of retry count is 0
 int value() default 0;
}
```

**Test.class**

```
@Test
@RetryCountIfFailed(100)
public void generateReports(String clientname, String username) {
    loginPage().login(clientname, username);
    loginPage().chooseReportManagement();
    reportPage().createReport();
}
```

You can refer to this link if this answer doesn't satisfy enough: [TestNG retryAnalyzer only works when defined in methods @Test, does not work in class' @Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871747/testng-retryanalyzer-only-works-when-defined-in-methods-test-does-not-work-in)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TestNG you can just add invocation count besides using for loop

```
@Test(invocationCount = 100)
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this, But it doesn't, I just need to repeat `createReport`. If we use `invocationCount`, it will loop also the action login and choose report management

Comment: you can remove the login part from this method and add it in BeforeMethod